# yaws failed to start yet erlang works very well

Tags: erlang, command-prompt, yaws

I downloaded and installed win32 yaws-1.98 installer for my win7 and tried to start it from windows command prompt with: `yaws -i`.  the result I got is just as right below. where I have placed @ was a simicolon.

Failed to create the process entirely.

Tried to invoke:  `erl.exe -pa "C:/Program Files/Yaws-1.98/ebin" -conf "C:\Program Files\Yaws-1.98\yaws.conf" -run yaws -yaws` id default @
Make sure you have erl in your environment PATH

after some research,  I placed the following paths in the O.S environment variables list separated by semicolon, first under the name ERL_LIBS and then PATH all with no change :

```
C:\Program Files\erl5.10.3\erts-5.10.3\bin
C:\Program Files\erl5.10.3\bin
```

what could I be missing
...s.b help.

Comment: I can tell you that ERL_LIBS is for Erlang BEAM files and not the erl.exe binary, but that shouldn't interfere with it. Also, in my experience, you have to restart Windows in order for environment variable changes to have an effect.

Comment: thx Soup, I actually restarted win but in vain...I later realised invoking yaws -i in cmd prompt without first invoking erl to create the erlang environment was the problem, that's why the shell couldn't access the erl.exe file.